# An item with the same key has already been added. IIS WCF Rest

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, iis-7

I am hosting WCF Rest service with my Asp.net Application, and asp.net compatibility mode is on ,it is working fine
when I run app from visual studio but when I in IIS7 I get error while accessing the End Point says "An item with the same key has already been added."
MY Service Cod is.

```
  [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements
    (RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class RestService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Site/{Id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Site GetSite(string Id)
        {
            return new Site(1);
        }
}
```

and global ASCX is

```
   protected void Application_Start ()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Rest", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RestService)));

       }
```

and web.config

```
     <system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

        <standardEndpoints>
               <webHttpEndpoint>
                    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
               </webHttpEndpoint>


        </standardEndpoints>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Note Every things working fine in VS2010 Mode but getting error in while Hosting IIS 7
and accessing  **http://example.com/rest/site/2** 
any Suggestion Please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IIS Under Advance Setting then Enabledd Protocols I switched off https and it works fine.
[image]

Comment: This is a prize-winning answer.  I was laid-low by the same annoying problem for an hour, stumbled across abdullah's post and removed the https protocol and suddenly everything worked perfectly.